# Composer Prototype of sonata bundles

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata, sonata-user-bundle

I have a project which has a bundles fixed on a specific commits of bundles or at dev-master version. i whould like to fix the dependency of this project and i secceed to fix the majority of my  bundles but i can't find the good combination of version of sonata bundles. And i got this error when i fixed the sonata bundles at dev-master version.

```
>   Problem 1
>     - Installation request for sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by
> sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle[dev-master].
>     - sonata-project/user-bundle dev-master conflicts with sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle[dev-master].
>     - Installation request for sonata-project/user-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by sonata-project/user-bundle[dev-master].
```

this is my composer configutation :

```
>   "require": {
>     "php": ">=5.3.9",
>     "symfony/symfony": "2.7.7",
>     "doctrine/orm": "2.4.8",
>     "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.6.2",
>     "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.8.0",
>     "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.11",
>     "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.10.0",
>     "sensio/distribution-bundle": "4.0.5",
>     "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "3.0.14",
>     "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "2.1.2",
>     "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "dev-master",
>     "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "dev-master",
>     "sonata-project/user-bundle": "dev-master",
>     "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "dev-master",
>     "sonata-project/datagrid-bundle": "dev-master",
>     "sonata-project/classification-bundle": "dev-master",
>     "sonata-project/intl-bundle": "dev-master",
>     "sonata-project/media-bundle": "dev-master",
>     "jms/serializer-bundle": "1.0.0",
>     "jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal": "1.0.*@beta",
>     "doctrine/phpcr-odm": "1.2.6",
>     "doctrine/phpcr-bundle": "1.2.4",
>     "phpcr/phpcr-utils": "1.2.4",
>     "sonata-project/formatter-bundle": "2.3.3",
>     "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "2.1.3",
>     "sonata-project/translation-bundle": "1.0.1",
>     "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "1.2.2",
>     "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "2.3.9",
>     "simplethings/entity-audit-bundle": "0.8",
>     "egeloen/ckeditor-bundle": "2.5.2",
>     "helios-ag/fm-elfinder-bundle": "5.3",
>     "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "1.5.4",
>     "sonata-project/jquery-bundle": "1.9.1",
>     "floriansemm/solr-bundle": "1.3.1",
>     "google/recaptcha": "1.1.2",
>     "friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle": "dev-master",
>     "presta/sitemap-bundle": "1.4",
>     "liuggio/excelbundle": "2.1.0"   },
```

any help please?
sorry for the english!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research I found a stable combination of bundle versions:
this is my composer.json
i wish that help

```
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.7.7",
    "doctrine/orm": "2.4.8",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.6.4",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.6.0",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.4.0",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.12",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "4.0.12",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "3.0.16",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "2.1.2",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "3.0",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "3.0.2",
    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "2.1.10",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "3.0.0",
    "sonata-project/datagrid-bundle": "2.2",
    "sonata-project/classification-bundle": "3.0.0",
    "sonata-project/intl-bundle": "2.2.4",
    "sonata-project/media-bundle": "3.0.0",
    "jms/serializer-bundle": "1.1.0",
    "jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal": "1.2.8",
    "doctrine/phpcr-odm": "1.3.0",
    "doctrine/phpcr-bundle": "1.2.1",
    "phpcr/phpcr-utils": "1.2.9",
    "sonata-project/formatter-bundle": "3.0.1",
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "2.1.2",
    "sonata-project/translation-bundle": "2.0.2",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "1.2.2",
    "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "2.3.9",
    "simplethings/entity-audit-bundle": "0.8",
    "egeloen/ckeditor-bundle": "4.0.6",
    "helios-ag/fm-elfinder-bundle": "5.3",
    "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "1.5.4",
    "sonata-project/jquery-bundle": "1.10.2",
    "floriansemm/solr-bundle": "1.3.1",
    "google/recaptcha": "1.1.2",
    "friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle": "3.2.1",
    "presta/sitemap-bundle": "1.4.1",
    "arodiss/xls-bundle": "0.5.9",
    "akeneo-labs/spreadsheet-parser": "1.2.2",
    "liuggio/excelbundle": "2.1.0"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove every sonata line from your composer.json
2. Let Composer figure out the working combination by itself : `composer require sonata-project/admin-bundle sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle sonata-project/user-bundle sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle sonata-project/datagrid-bundle sonata-project/classification-bundle sonata-project/intl-bundle sonata-project/media-bundle`

Also, don't use `dev-master` if you can avoid it. It's not meant for that, it's meant for when you are developing Sonata itself.